# Unexpected behaviour in test with fakeAsync(), NgModel and detectChanges()

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

The view of my component must display some checkboxes generated from component data (and conditionally checked and binded by [(NgModel)] ).

```
<div *ngFor="let checkableColumn of visibleCatalog">
  <label nz-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checkableColumn.checked">
    {{ checkableColumn.column.label | titlecase }}
  </label>
</div>
```

I've understood that NgModel updating is async so I put my test in a fakeAsnyc context to keep the test simpler.

My first try was:

```
it('should update his checkboxes', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.ngOnChanges({}); // For populating my data

  fixture.detectChanges();
  tick();

  const checkboxesChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  expect(checkboxesChecked.length).withContext('1 checkbox should be checked').toBe(1);
}));
```

But it did not work, no checkboxes was selected, and I found that the following did:

```
it('should update his checkboxes', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.ngOnChanges({}); // For populating my data

  fixture.detectChanges(); // Added
  tick();
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const checkboxesChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  expect(checkboxesChecked.length).withContext('1 checkbox should be checked').toBe(1);
}));
```

I cannot understand why I need to update my view before the tick().. 
Does anyone understand this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very nice if tricky question.

It seems from [angular documentation on testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing) that the first **detectChanges** only goes through the onInit(). In order to see your async changes then you need to go through the tick and run again, as the async process to update has not yet started (it only starts after the component is initialized).

```
it('should display error when TwainService fails', fakeAsync(() => {
  // tell spy to return an error observable
  getQuoteSpy.and.returnValue(
    throwError('TwainService test failure'));

  fixture.detectChanges(); // onInit()
  // sync spy errors immediately after init

  tick(); // flush the component's setTimeout()

  fixture.detectChanges(); // update errorMessage within setTimeout()

  expect(errorMessage()).toMatch(/test failure/, 'should display error');
  expect(quoteEl.textContent).toBe('...', 'should show placeholder');
}));
```

As for the synchronous case angular states the following:

> Because the spy result returns synchronously, the getQuote() method
>   updates the message on screen immediately after the first change
>   detection cycle during which Angular calls ngOnInit.
>
> You're not so lucky when testing the error path. Although the service
>   spy will return an error synchronously, the component method calls
>   setTimeout(). The test must wait at least one full turn of the
>   JavaScript engine before the value becomes available. The test must
>   become asynchronous.